# Form that uses array, assign object to array

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I need to create a form that allows the user to select a number from 0 to 7 and "show all" and the script will then output the object found in that train car to the user, or if show all is picked then it runs a loop that shows all 8 objects along with the train number. But my code doesn't really run.
(Please ignore my code if it doesn't make any sense, but I don't seem to get arrays :( Please point out the mistakes and thank you so so so much)

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="train" method="GET" action="test.php">

<select>
<option value="0" name="object">0</option>
<option value="1" name="object">1</option>
<option value="2" name="object">2</option>
<option value="3" name="object">3</option>
<option value="4" name="object">4</option>
<option value="5" name="object">5</option>
<option value="6" name="object">6</option>
<option value="7" name="object">7</option>
<option value="8" name="object">8</option>
<option value="all" name="all">Show All</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" size="10">
</form>

<?php

$train[0] ="pencil";
$train[1] = "macaron";
$train[2] = "notes";
$train[3] = "book";
$train[4] = "eraser";
$train[5] = "cake";
$train[6] = "laptop";
$train[7] = "mint";
$train[8] = "cup";

if ($_GET['submit']) { 
  $train = $_GET['object']; 
  echo "<p>I have $train!</p>";
}

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($train); $i++) {
  echo "<li>" . $train[$i] . "</li>";
}   

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$train = $_GET['obejct']; ` - "obejct" is spelled incorrectly. Should be "object"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form that uses array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306183/form-that-uses-array)

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in the code

- Select should have name attribute
- Need to get object and display results based on the selected option.

Use the below code

```
<form name="train" method="GET" >

<select name="object">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  ......
  <option value="all">Show All</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit" size="10">
</form>
```

PHP code

```
$train[0] ="pencil";
....
$train[8] = "cup";

if ($_GET['submit']) { 
  $object = $_GET['object'];
  if($object == 'all'){
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($train); $i++) {
        echo "<li>" . $train[$i] . "</li>";
    }
  }else{
    echo "<p>I have $train[$object]!</p>";
  } 

}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestions :) but this still doesnt seem to run :( it doesnt echo properly for some reason.

Comment: @meowwwwww Your other question will likely be closed to link against this one. It would help if you identified exactly what output this does produce, and how it differs from what you expect. If you get _no_ output, it is possible due to a fatal error in your code. Always when developing and testing code, at the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` -- which will reveal coding & syntax errors to correct before attempting to correct logic errors.